# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope

For the below code,

```
// Print indexes
var randArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
for(var val in randArray){ // val is type inferred to String type
  document.write(val + "<br>");
}
// Print values
for(var val of randArray){ // Line 95
  document.write(val + "<br>");
}
```

---

Below is the error,

```
tstut.ts(95,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'val' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.
```

---

Below code,

```
// Print indexes
var randArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
for(var index in randArray){
  document.write(index + "<br>");
}
// Print values
for(var val of randArray){
  document.write(val + "<br>");
}
```

resolves the problem.

---

In problem case, Why `val` type cannot be `number` type?

Comment: You're trying to coerce `val` to a string. Maybe the error will go away if you use `val.toString() + "<br>"`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, Coersion does not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy fix to your code is to change `var` to [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
// Print indexes
var randArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
for(let val in randArray){
  console.log(val);
}
// Print values
for(let val of randArray){
  console.log(val);
}
```

Your problem has it's root in how `var` keyword scopes the variable. (See the [manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html).) `var` declarations' scope is the enclosing functions, thus your second `for(var val...)` point in fact to the same variable and in TypeScript, they have a single, defined type. `let` instead scopes the variable in to the enclosing block or `for`, which means that the two variables can have same name, but are still separate variables.

Comment: With `var` keyword, does scope of `val` in first loop is visible in second for loop? Is this a variable scope problem?

Comment: From the [manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html): "When a variable is declared using let, it uses what some call lexical-scoping or block-scoping. Unlike variables declared with var whose scopes leak out to their containing function, block-scoped variables are not visible outside of their nearest containing block or for-loop."

Comment: @overexchange yes. `var` is not block scoped

Answer (score 0):

Using "for..in" in JavaScript exposes the **key/index** of an array , simply 'coz it doesn't iterate over array items, instead it iterates over the keys/index in an array. For example,

```js
var randArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
for(let val in randArray){
  document.write(val + "<br>");
}
```

In above code, no matter what items does "randArray" array contains its always going to throw the indexes.

"for..of" comes to the rescue. This is one of the reasons why "for..of" exists in TypeScript (and ES6). The above code with "for..of" loop will iterate over items in an array.

Also, replace "var" with "let" 'coz "let" keyword binds the variable to the local scope unlike "var" keyword in JavaScript.